# How to use pagelist with data source as multiple tables, to display table values in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

First of all I dont know how to ask this question.I need to do this in MVC.
I have two(or more) tables that is having common field. I want to display its values inside view in single table. How can I do this? Can anyone provide some links? I haven't used pagelist yet. But think that will be the option to do this. 
it will be good if I get a solution with pagelist and linq.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net will give you the answer 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

the different between using pagelist is on the controller
you pass the value **page**

declare those variable

```
    int pageSize = 5;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
```

`var query = context.Model.ToList();` // do your query

pass it to the view like this `View(query.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize))`

and in your view you will not use **IEnumerable** or **List**  but declare your model like this `@model PagedList.IPagedList<MyModel>`